# Variable Not holding values

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with a program I am trying to create. This program is like a credit card and the issue is that the amount of money I put in the 'Credit' variable doesn't seem to affect the variable at all, it stays empty.
The following is the Credit Card class:

I have edited the code because I have just noticed I did not insert everything and have also included the program.cs!  The outcome of this program when it runs: https://prnt.sc/jynpt1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreditCardExample
{
    public class CreditCard
    {
            private double credit;
            public double Credit
            {
                get { return credit; }
                set { credit = value; }
            }

            public CreditCard(double credit)
            {
                this.credit = Credit;
            }

            public bool enoughCredit (double creditAmt)
            {
                bool state = false;
                if (Credit >= creditAmt)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You have sufficient funds.");
                    state = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You do not have sufficient amount");
                    state = false;
                }

                return state;
            }
        public double getAmtInCreditCard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of Money in your CreditCard: ", Credit);
            return Credit;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CreditCardExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {



            CreditCardExample.CreditCard c = new 
            CreditCardExample.CreditCard(20.0);
            c.enoughCredit(12);
            c.getAmtInCreditCard();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "it stays empty"? Can you show how you're using the class? (As an aside, you can do without the separate `credit` variable - use an automatically implemented property: `public double Credit { get; set; }`. Ideally don't use `double` for currency, either - `decimal` would be a better type to use.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bug in your code.

```
 public CreditCard(double credit)
 {
      Credit = credit;
 }
```

Test:

```
class CreditCard
{
    private double credit;
    public double Credit
    {
        get { return credit; }
        set { credit = value; }
    }

    public CreditCard(double credit)
    {
        Credit = credit;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    //Outputs "10"
    Console.WriteLine(new CreditCard(10).Credit);
}
```

Comment: @Mariz: To help you, we're going to need more information. You need to be clearer about what code you're using to call this class, and what happens. Ideally, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Mariz That's impossible with the code you posted.  See my edit.

Comment: I have tried this line of code >  Console.WriteLine(new CreditCard(10).Credit); but it still says 0 and not 10

Comment: @DaisyShipton  I have uploaded all the code and a screenshot of it when it runs :)

Comment: @Mariz Did you fix the bug in your constructor?  Please post a complete example that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: Oh guys! it was just a silly mistake! i wrote Console.WriteLine("Amount of Money in your CreditCard:  ", Credit); instead of Console.WriteLine("Amount of Money in your CreditCard:  "+ Credit); ! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I did @Zer0 and it was another error from my part because I'm just retrying it with the way I have done it originally and it wouldn't have worked anyway! I did it the way you told me to and now works perfectly! Thanks for saving me  :D

Answer (score 6):

That's because in your constructor you are assigning the property back to itself and not the value being passed i.e.

```
this.credit = Credit // notice the casing?
```

Change to

```
this.credit = credit;
```

Comment: I also suggest to rename the class-wide variable with a leading underscore, as follows: _credit. Just make the code more readable, at least in my opinion.

Comment: I have tried, but the variable still stays empty when I pass a  value

Comment: I'd recommend one of two things if you use this solution.  Either get rid of the property setter, or do not assign directly to the field.  This code will introduce bugs if the property setter later is more complex and not a simple assign as it is currently.

Comment: @Zer0 my answer was simply pointing out the error and correcting it, the code functions and is fine. I'm not going to get into debates about coding style because it's off-topic and doesn't add any value to the question IMO.

Comment: @MarioVernari my answer was simply pointing out the error and correcting it, the code functions and is fine. I'm not going to get into debates about coding style because it's off-topic and doesn't add any value to the question IMO.

Comment: @James This has nothing to do with coding style whatsoever.  I specifically mentioned this code can introduce bugs if the `setter` on the `Credit` property becomes more complex.  By directly accessing the field you're bypassing any potential important logic in the `setter`.  Simple as that.  This is plain bad code.  Concrete example.  Say later the property changes to: `public double Credit {
        get { return credit; } set { if (value >= 0 && value <= 10000) credit = value; }  }`.  Your solution bypasses that logic and could introduce bugs.

Comment: @Zer0 you're implying that the code is *potentially* bad and as such should be written in a different way yet both will accomplish the same result, that suggests coding style to me. Setting the internal field in a constructor is **not** bad code, particularly when it's clear to see the actual property implementation is effectively doing the exact same thing. You're making up problems to suit your argument e.g. what if the OP wanted to set an initial value that couldn't be achieved via the setter logic? How does the OP achieve that without writing "bad" code as you like to call it?

Comment: @Jamie Correct.  Code changes.  Often.  Coding saying "oh this works today" is exactly how companies end up in mountains of technical debt.  And I already answered your last question.  Get rid of the setter.  Done.  If the setter exists then it *should* be used.  Period.  Not exactly complicated.  This is future-proofing code.  Anyways this is nothing new and has been part of best practices for a very long time.  As for your other question, C# has readonly Properties.  Or simply define a Property without a setter and use a method?  This isn't a complex subject.

Comment: @Jamie in short, you're completely disregarding the mutability of code and calling that "making things up".  I don't think I know a single developer that would let this pass a code review as is.  No point in arguing it; you won't change your mind and there's literally no advantage to doing it your way.  This information *should* be known to others so they don't fall into this, apparently easy, trap.  The very second the setter changes you potentially have a bug. 
 And it takes, what, all of two seconds of foresight to prevent this?  Mmk.

Comment: @Zer0 *"if the setter exists then it should be used. Period"* - it is, externally, there are no rules saying if a property has a setter it needs to also be used internally, the whole point of setters / getters is to accomplish encapsulation... internal code is already privvy to what goes on inside the class so the only thing you are accomplishing here is reusability. FWIW the question was rhetorical, I was making  a point that when you start making assumptions about code you can end up down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @Zer0 also, I'm well aware of the pros & cons of property setters / getters and FWIW I am in no way saying using properties is _wrong_ and the OP shouldn't do it - I merely answered the question based on the OPs _existing_ code. Nothing wrong with suggesting the OP use the property....but it's the fact you deemed it "bad code" which is complete nonsense.